# CakePHP - Blank page on navigating to page

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, view, model

I have the following controller method:

```
function recover_password() {
        $this->layout = 'frontend';
        $this->loadModel('PasswordReset');
        $this->Fonyker->recusive = -1;

        if($this->data) {
            $fields = array(
                'Fonyker.fonykid',
                'Fonyker.username',
                'Fonyker.name',
                'Fonyker.email'
            );

            $fonyker = $this->Fonyker->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'OR' => array(
                        'Fonyker.email' => $this->data['Fonyker']['field'],
                        'Fonyker.username' => $this->data['Fonyker']['field']
                    ) 
                ),
                'fields' => $fields
            ));

            if($fonyker) {
                $this->PasswordReset->create();

                $passwordReset = array();
                $passwordReset = array(
                    'PasswordReset' => array(
                        'code' => hash('sha256', $fonyker['Fonyker']['fonykid'].StringUtils::getRandomString(20)),
                        'fonykid' => $fonyker['Fonyker']['fonykid']
                    )
                );

                $this->PasswordReset->save($passwordReset);

                $data = array(
                    'username' => $fonyker['Fonyker']['username'],
                    'code' => $passwordReset['PasswordReset']['code'],
                    'name' => $fonyker['Fonyker']['name'],
                    'email' => $fonyker['Fonyker']['email']
                );

                $this->_sendPasswordResetEmail($data);

            } else {

            }
        } 
    }
```

This is the view:

```
<div class="prepend-top span-24">
    <div class="prepend-8 span-8 append-8">
        <?php

            echo $this->Form->create('Fonyker', array('action' => 'recover_password'));
            echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
                'div' => array(
                    'class' => 'span-8'
                ),
                'class' => 'input-text long',
                'id' => 'FonykerEmail',
                'label' => array(
                    'class' => 'inlined',
                    'text' => ''
                ),
                'placeholder' => 'Username or Email'
            ));

            echo $this->Form->submit('',array(
                'div' => array(
                    'class' => 'span-2 last'
                ),
            ));

            echo $this->Form->end();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I navigate to the page all I get is a blank page, and sometimes this error: `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in Unknown on line 0`

UPDATE: The error seems to be loading my model, this is the model I have declared:

```
<?php
class PassswordReset extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'PasswordReset';
    var $displayField = 'id';
    var $validate = array(
        'code' => array(
            'alphanumeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('alphanumeric'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'fonykid' => array(
            'alphanumeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('alphanumeric'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        )
    );
}
?>
```

If I remove the `loadModel()` call the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a table in the database called password_resets? Also, you may want to move your loadModel to the line right before you need it.

Comment: Yes, I do. And will do, thank you. I already fixed this issue, for some reason PasswordReset seems to be reserved by the system, when I changed the DB table and Model name to recoveries/Recovery it all worked fine.